# Kendo grid without any border

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I want a kendo Grid without any border i.e. plane background with no Outer border and also no border to 'tr','th' and 'td's

Can we have CSS for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
.k-grid, .k-grid div, .k-grid table, .k-grid thead, 
.k-grid tbody, .k-grid th, .k-grid tr, .k-grid td{
   border: 0 !important;
}
```